# A (deep) cloning method for ES-Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have written a (recursive) deep clone method for ES/JS-objects. It seems [to work fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mv1vqt?file=ObjectClone.js), but maybe I'm missing things. Please, feel free to comment!

**Note**: the method will not clone [cyclic structures](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/14476/cyclic-object-values). If it should be somehow necessary to be able to clone such structures, maybe [Crockfords cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) can be used - but it will [mangle the structure](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cloning-with-cyclic-structures?file=index.js).

```js
initializeObjCloner();
const log = Logger();
// initial object
const test1 = {
  foo: [1, 2 ,3],
  bar: { foo: {bar: 5}, foobar: "foobar", bar2: {bar3: {foo: 42}} },
};
// clone it
const test2 = Object.clone(test1);
// change a few props to demonstrate
// test2 not being a reference to test1
test2.bar.foo.foobar = "barfoo";
test2.bar.bar2.bar3.foo = 43;
test2.foo = test2.foo.map(v => v + 10);
test2.test2Only = "not in test1";
log (`**Test1:`, test1, `\n**Test2:`, test2);

// error on cyclic structures
const c = {hello: "world"};
c.recycled = c;
log(`\n${Object.clone(c)}`);


function initializeObjCloner() {
  const isImmutable = val =>
    val === null || 
    val === undefined || 
    [String, Boolean, Number].find(V => val.constructor === V);
  const isObject = obj =>
    (obj.constructor !== Date && 
    JSON.stringify(obj) === "{}") || 
    Object.keys(obj).length;
  const cloneArr = arr => arr.reduce( (acc, value) => 
    [...acc, isObject(value) ? cloneObj(value) : value], []);
  const isCyclic = obj => {
    try {
      JSON.stringify(obj);
    } catch(err) {
      return err.message;
    }
    return null;
  };
  // --------------------------
  // The actual cloning method
  // --------------------------
  const cloneObj = (obj) => {
    const cyclic = isCyclic(obj);
    return cyclic ? 
      `Object.clone error: Cyclic structures can not be cloned, sorry.` :
      Object.keys(obj).length === 0 ? obj :
        Object.entries(obj)
        .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => ( {
            ...acc,
            [key]: 
              value instanceof Array 
              ? cloneArr(value) :
                !isImmutable(value) && isObject(value)
                  ? cloneObj(value)
                  : value && value.constructor
                    ? new value.constructor(value)
                    : value } ),  {} );
  };
  Object.clone = cloneObj;
}

function Logger() {
  const report =
    document.querySelector("#report") ||
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement(
      "beforeend",
      Object.assign(document.createElement("pre"), { id: "report" })
    );
  return (...args) =>
    args.forEach(
      arg =>
        (report.textContent +=
          (arg instanceof Object ? JSON.stringify(arg, null, 2) : arg) + "\n")
    );
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

if readability is an issue, `cloneObj` may also be written as:

```
function cloneObj(obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj).length < 1) { return obj; }
  
  if (obj.constructor === Date) {
    return new Date(obj);
  }
  
  if (obj.constructor === Array) {
    return cloneArr(obj);
  }

  let newObj = {};

  for ( let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj) ) {
    if (!isImmutable(value) && isObject(value)) {
      newObj[key] = cloneObj(value);
    }

    if (!newObj[key] && value && value.constructor) {
      newObj[key] = new value.constructor(value);
    }
    
    if (!newObj[key]) {
      newObj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return newObj;
};
```

Comment: You are missing several small functions, making this code not work without them. This is grounds to get this question closed on CodeReview. Also, this code cannot handle cyclic structures, which are sadly more common than you would think.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mv1vqt?file=index.js)?

Comment: Yes, it throws an error on a cyclical object. `JSON.stringify` falls over.

Comment: Ok, so it's [not suitable for cyclic structures](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-no-cloning-with-cyclic-structures?file=index.js), thnx for pointing that out.

Comment: Yes, can you also fix this question and add `isImmutable`, `cloneArr` etc.

Comment: I don't really like longer snippets in questions/answers, but hey, it's done

Comment: Deep cloning is always a difficult task that can never be done perfectly. What might work in one use case will cause issues in another. Some things to consider: If an object is frozen/sealed, do you want to copy that over? If a property is not enumerable, should that copy over? What about getters and setters? functions? symbols? Objects with prototypes? There's no right way to handle all of these scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

I spent a ton of time on this;

- The choice to replicate `Date` but not the other [50+ built-ins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) is interesting
- I would write `isObject` as `const isObject = x => (typeof x === 'object' && x !== null)`
- A question to ask yourself, what about functions, do you want to clone those as well?
- `if (Object.keys(obj).length < 1) { return obj; }` is interesting, this means you will allow for modifications in the original object to impact the new object
- The poor man's deep clone for non-cyclic structures is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o))`
- After the construction here: `newObj[key] = new value.constructor(value);` I would still copy over the properties as well
- Still mulling over a counter example..